# Break the scene to several canvases or keep redrawing one?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, vector-graphics, html5-canvas

Intent on creating a canvas-based game in javascript I stand before a choice:

Should I performance-wise keep all the stuff happening in the screen in one canvas (all the moving characters, sprites) and redraw it at constant rate of, say, 60 FPS or should I break the scene into several smaller canvases thus removing the need of redundant redrawing of the scene? I could even create separate canvas elements for the characters' limbs and then do most of the animation by simply manipulating the CSS of the given canvas element (rotation, positioning, opacity).

To me the latter sounds way more plausible and easier to implement, but is it also faster? Also, shouldn't I perhaps use SVG, keep the characters and sprites as elements inside of it and manipulate their XML and CSS properties directly?

So what do you think is the most fitting solution to a scene with severals sprites and characters:

- One canvas object redrawn manually (and wastefully) at FPS rate
- Several canvas elements, redrawn manually in a more reasonable fashion
- Structured vector graphics document like SVG / VML manipulated via DOM

I am mainly concerned about the performance differences, but the legibility of the logical code behind is also of interest (I, having already worked with canvas before, am for example fairly sure that the redrawing function for the entire canvas would be one hard-to-maintain beast of a script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM manipulations are slow in comparison to GPU-accelerated canvas operations, so I would stay away from SVG and VML.

As far as structuring your canvas code goes, it certainly doesn't make sense (especially for performance reasons) to clear and re-draw the entire canvas because the player moved or performed an action. Based on your description here, I'm guessing that your game will be 2D. These types of games lend themselves extremely well to layering unless you're doing something rather complex like Paper Mario. You should be looking at the issue from an object-oriented viewpoint and encapsulating your drawing procedures and objects together as appropriate.

For instance, create a player object that maintains a small canvas representing the character. All the logic needed to maintain the character's state is kept within the object and any changes made to it need not worry about other components of the game's visual representation. Likewise, do the same for the background, user interface, and anything else you can abstract into a layer (within reason). For example, if you're doing a parallax game, you might have a `foreground`, `background`, `character`, and `user interface` layer.

Ultimately you will need to maintain the state of the different components in your game individually. Player animations, background clouds moving, trees swaying, etc. will all be managed by appropriate objects. Since you will already have that type of code structure setup, it makes sense to just maintain major components on separate canvas elements and composite them together as needed for better performance. If the character moves in the bottom left corner of a scene with a static background, you don't need to re-draw the top right corner (or 95% of the scene, for that matter). If you're considering full-screen capabilities, this is definitely a performance concern.

Comment: Thanks. That was pretty exhaustive and supports what I have thought. I like the idea of the abstraction provided by this design approach as I've already said in the original post. Here's to ask, however, whether moving the for example player tile via CSS absolute positioning really is faster than GPU-accelerated canvas redrawing. I suppose I'll go and run some tests. :)

Comment: @Witiko You're welcome! I'll admit that I can't say for sure which approach would be faster, but I would be inclined to believe that sliding a player tile around via CSS positioning would be faster. It's true that DOM manipulation is comparatively slow, but in this case we're talking about having to clear the entire canvas and then re-draw all the elements (background, UI, etc). For a small resolution game, it probably doesn't matter too much. For something running at 30fps in 1080p, I'd try the CSS approach first. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a rule in programming, that you should never try and optimize something before you have a speed problem with it. You'll spend more time trying to figure out how to code something in the best way than to actually code, and will never finish anything.

Draw them all on your canvas at a fixed rate. That's how it's done. If you start creating a canvas for each limb and element and manipulate them using CSS, you're wasting the potential of canvas. Might as well just use images. That's how they did it before canvas. That's the problem canvas was made to solve.

If you ever encounter speed issues, then you can start hammering at them. [Check out these slides](http://io-2011-html5-games.appspot.com/#47) for some tips ([related video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEocRtn_j9s)). [This guy's blog](http://simonsarris.com/) also has some handy tips on canvas performance.

Comment: "There's a rule in programming, that you should never try and optimize something before you have a speed problem with it." - As I said this is hardly just about the performance. I am quite convinced that separating the stuff would make the code more transparent.

Comment: "Might as well just use images." - I was actually going to do that - thinking of `drawImage()`ing SVG images into the canvas and caching them as data URI for further `drawImage()`ing, as some of the stuctures and sprites are quite complex and defining then in the code would be nothing short of an overkill (and a nightmare as for the separation of style and logic definition).

Comment: Well you know your project best. You could always try some small testcases and see what you like most.

Comment: Right, thanks for the advise and that guy's blog - he's got a lot of valuable information and research results there. :-)